# Parsing TreeStore data even collapsed nodes

Tags: extjs

I have a TreePanel and its TreeStore and Model.
I've added nodes to the Tree by using `node.appendChild( newNode );` not using the store.

Now I need to parse all nodes. I've tried this:

```
dataPanelsStore.each(function(record,id){
    console.log(record);
});
```

but noticed this will parse only expanded nodes (the visible ones).

how can I parse everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atleast from 5.1.2 you can pass includedOptions object to [treestore#each](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.data.TreeStore.html#method-each) method:

I tried using 5.1.1.451-Gray in fiddle , it still displayed only expanded nodes. It worked fine though after copying TreeStore.js code to fiddle.

So this is what you can do:

```
Ext.getStore('treestore').each(function(record,id){
    if(record.id !== 'root')
    console.log(record.data.name);
},this,{collapsed:true});
```

You can also pass filtered:true in third parameter object to include filtered out nodes.

Here is a full example you can copy to fiddle and run:

```
    Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    launch : function() {
       Ext.define('myApp.Territory', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
    fields: [{
        name: 'text',
        mapping: 'name'
    }]
});
Ext.define('myApp.Country', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
    fields: [{
        name: 'text',
        mapping: 'name'
    }]
});
Ext.define('myApp.City', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
    fields: [{
        name: 'text',
        mapping: 'name'
    }]
});
var tp = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    title: 'Sales Areas - using typeProperty',
    rootVisible: false,
    store: {
        // Child types use namespace of store's model by default
        storeId:'treestore',
        model: 'myApp.Territory',
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                typeProperty: 'mtype'
            }
        },
        root: {
            children: [{
                name: 'Europe, ME, Africa',
                mtype: 'Territory',
                children: [{
                    name: 'UK of GB & NI',
                    mtype: 'Country',
                    children: [{
                        name: 'London',
                        mtype: 'City',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
                name: 'North America',
                mtype: 'Territory',
                children: [{
                    name: 'USA',
                    mtype: 'Country',
                    children: [{
                        name: 'Redwood City',
                        mtype: 'City',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
});
Ext.getStore('treestore').each(function(record,id){
    if(record.id !== 'root')
    console.log(record.data.name);
},this,{collapsed:true});
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain the `collapsed:true` parameter? In second code, I don't want to expand anything. Can't mess with the tree.

Comment: As the doc explains, by adding `{collapsed:true}` in iteration it will process children of collapsed nodes too. you don't need to expand any node, I just did to show you , updated fiddle by removing the line that expands.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing node means, to get each node data irrespective of expanded or not?

If so, please look into this method [cascade](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html#method-cascade) method.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I need to do some processing and need to get each node data. I think the, lets say `correct`, way is to search over the store and not the tree nodes itself but I'll give a try.

Comment: If the store which is bind to the tree is filtered then the filtered records will only get displayed in tree. And Ext.store.each method will go over only the filtered records.

Comment: The store is not filtered. Seems it can only "see" the expanded nodes.... If I expand all, then all works fine but I can't expand all the tree because the user still using it.

Comment: I can see that the treestore itself is loading the data when the nodes get expanded. i.e. the node/record is not available unless you expand it by means of store. You can check that both getCount() & getTotalCount() returns the same count.

Comment: The node is available in store when its parent is expanded by code or by clicking in tree. Not before.